# Questions about CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, yuv

I attempt to extract yuv data from the pixel buffer received from camera and then re-create a pixel buffer, but I got -6683 at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage, the documentation simply states that

> The pixel buffer is not compatible with OpenGL due to an unsupported buffer size, pixel format, or attribute.

Which does not help me much. How can I fix it? The code as below:

```
- (void)Init
{
    *****;
    OSStatus err = CMBufferQueueCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 1, CMBufferQueueGetCallbacksForUnsortedSampleBuffers(), &previewBufferQueue);

}
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
    didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{


  OSStatus err = CMBufferQueueEnqueue(previewBufferQueue, sampleBuffer);
  if ( !err ) {        
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CMSampleBufferRef sbuf = (CMSampleBufferRef)CMBufferQueueDequeueAndRetain(previewBufferQueue);
        if (sbuf) {
            CVImageBufferRef pixBuf = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sbuf);
            [self.delegate displayPixelBuffer:pixBuf];
            CFRelease(sbuf);
         }
     });
   }
}
```

The displayPixelBuffer method:

```
-(void)displayPixelBuffer:(CVImageBufferRef)pixelBuffer
{
     CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
     size_t planeWidth[2] = {CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0), width};
     size_t planeHeight[2] = {CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0),  
     CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1)};
     size_t planeBytesPerRow[2] = {CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0), width/2};

    unsigned char *YUV2[2] = {0};
    YUV2[0] = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
    YUV2[1] = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);

    CVReturn renturn = CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                      width, 
                                                      height,
                                                      kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange, 
                                                      0,
                                                      0,
                                                      2, 
                                                      (void *)YUV2,
                                                      planeWidth,
                                                      planeHeight, 
                                                      planeBytesPerRow, 
                                                      nil,
                                                      nil, nil, &imageBuffer);


   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
   CVOpenGLESTextureRef texture = NULL;
   CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                            videoTextureCache,
                                                            imageBuffer,
                                                            NULL,
                                                            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                            GL_LUMINANCE,
                                                            width,
                                                            height,
                                                            GL_LUMINANCE,
                                                            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                            0,
                                                            &texture);

   if (!texture || err) {
      NSLog(@"CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage failed (error: %d)", err);  
      return;
   }
    glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(texture), 0);

   // Flush the CVOpenGLESTexture cache and release the texture
   CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(videoTextureCache, 0);
   CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
   CFRelease(texture);

}
```

The result is CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage failed(error:-6683), why?

Comment: Hi Sam, I get stuck with the same error message. Did you ever find out what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Same here. Would be great if you could update.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the CVPixelBuffer needs to be an ioSurfaceBacked.

Answer (score 1):

You acquired the property values for creating the texture from the image buffer incorrectly. Here's how it'a

```
done:

- (void)displayPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer
{
    CVReturn err;
    if (pixelBuffer != NULL) {
        int frameWidth = (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
        int frameHeight = (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);



        /*
         CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage will create GLES texture optimally from CVPixelBufferRef.
         */

        /*
         Create Y and UV textures from the pixel buffer. These textures will be drawn on the frame buffer Y-plane.
         */
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                           _videoTextureCache,
                                                           pixelBuffer,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                           GL_RED_EXT,
                                                           frameWidth,
                                                           frameHeight,
                                                           GL_RED_EXT,
                                                           GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                           0,
                                                           &_lumaTexture);
        if (err) {
            NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
        }

        glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_lumaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_lumaTexture));
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        // UV-plane.
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                           _videoTextureCache,
                                                           pixelBuffer,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                           GL_RG_EXT,
                                                           frameWidth / 2,
                                                           frameHeight / 2,
                                                           GL_RG_EXT,
                                                           GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                           1,
                                                           &_chromaTexture);
        if (err) {
            NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
        }

        glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_chromaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_chromaTexture));
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBufferHandle);

    }
```

This was copied from AVBasicVideoOutput/APLEAGLView.m on the ADC site. It's what I use, and everyone else that publicly publish their code (that actually works). If there are a thousand ways to do this, I've tried all thousand of them. This is the way.

NOTE | This is OpenGL 2.0; if you're ready for 3.0, I have an upgraded version of the AVBasicVideoOutput on my blog at:

http://demonicactivity.blogspot.com/2016/02/technology-apples-opengl-related-sample.html?m=1